# Probabilty Combinatorial related; The Messy Mail Man

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given the messy mail man problem of n pieces of mail, and X RV which value is "how many pieces of mail arrived to the right mail box," how do I compute E(X)?

I saw a solution using indicators, but I didnt really get it, so the more explanation or links to good sources in that subject would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the messy mailman distributes the mail independently at random, then this is the same problem as the expected number of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) in a random permutation.

Comment: If the letters go independently, you don't have a permutation.  And you mean the expected number of fixed points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're talking about a random permutation of $n$ letters.  Let $X_i$ be the random variable that is $1$ if letter number $i$ is placed in the correct box, $0$ if not.  Then $X$, the number of letters placed in the correct box, is $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Since expected value is linear, $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]$.  Now what is the probability that letter $i$ is placed in the correct box?